# junit 5 code/configuration reuse. should i use abstract test class or an extension?

Tags: java, junit, junit5

junit 5 docs is using [AbstractDatabaseTests](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#:%7E:text=AbstractDatabaseTests)

but i remember recommended way for junit 4 was to use rules rather than extending classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [example](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-execution-order-wrapping-behavior) using an `AbstractDatabaseTest` is there to demonstrate that "JUnit Jupiter also [in addition to registered extensions] guarantees wrapping behavior within class and interface hierarchies […]".

From the [user guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/#overview-what-is-junit-5):

> **JUnit Jupiter** is the combination of the [programming model](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/#writing-tests) and [extension model](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/#extensions) for writing tests […]

Extensions are a core JUnit Jupiter feature and are considered more idiomatic than using inheritance.

While JUnit Jupiter also supports inheritance (many annotations are [`@Inherited`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html)), the extensions mechanism follows the principle of [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). This gives you, for instance, more flexibility as you can use multiple extensions, whereas inheritance is limited to a single class.